# Can't change dialer default app

Tags: phone-app, default-applications, huawei

I installed Full Screen Caller ID (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androminigsm.fscifree&hl=en), but it doesn't work.

I searched about it, they say you should clear defaults of the default dialer app, but I can't find it in Manage Apps.

I have a Huawei Honor 3C, Android 4.2.2, EmoutionUI 2.0.

Comment: Try with settings -> application manager -> your default dialer, you should see a 'clear defaults' button

Comment: I cannot find my default dialer in settings>manage apps (like I said in my question).